# problem with selenium on the anaconda navigator terminal(windows 10)

Tags: python, selenium, anaconda, jupyter-lab

I am trying to start on the anaconda navigator terminal with the jupyter lab command.

It says `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'selenium'.`

While on the interface of anaconda navigator selenium is well installed. Could someone help me please?

[code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RGQYO.png)

Comment: What have you already tried? Please do your research before you ask a question. Also please never include your code within an image. Please see [ask]?

Answer (score 0):

Selenium package is not installed in your machine. That is the reason you cant import it.
you can install selenium by using following commands on terminal.

```
pip install selenium
```

or

```
sudo pip3 install selenium
```